# Linq - improve .Max()-query to execute everything inside the database instead of the C# app

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, query-optimization, database-performance

The importent part of our DbVersion model looks like this:

```
    public class DatabaseVersion
    {
        .....
        public int Major { get; set; }
        public int Minor { get; set; }
        .....
        public Version Version => new Version(Major, MinorVersion);
    }
```

The `Version` property is not mapped to a database column but rather computed by the C# application. So a query to get the max version of the database looks like this:

```
context.DatabaseVersions.ToList().Max(x => x.Version)
```

which is bad. It downloads all versions into memory and the looks for the latest version. I would like to improve this query but i am not able to write a linq query that gets the highest MajorVersion and for that the highest minor version.

How can that be done?

Comment: Because .Net Core 6.0 throws an exception without the .ToList() saying no mapping exist cannot create sql statement. In .Net Core versions < 3.0 it was working because it got implicitly downloaded into the client memory

Comment: If Version is not in the database what is in the database that can be used for computation of what you want to know?

Comment: Think about how you would write that in SQL: `ORDER BY Major DESC, Minor DESC`, and take the first row. Now write the LINQ version of that.

Comment: Hi @Ralf the Major and Minor properties are presenting database columns. Version the then computed

Comment: Hi @madreflection - hah of course! (:  ok i go with plain SQL instead and worry about LINQ later

Comment: Why? You can write the LINQ equivalent to that now. My point was to think about the kind of SQL you want to generate, to help you visualize the problem.

Comment: I dont know ... its late ... ok oderby .. thenby - you are right

Comment: Close. You'll want `OrderByDescending`, etc. (I updated my earlier comment... originally forgot `DESC`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct order may help:

```cs
var letest = context.DatabaseVersions
    .OrderByDescending(v => v.Major)
    .ThenByDescensing(v => v.MinorVersion)
    .Select(v => new Version(v.Major, v.MinorVersion))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```